# Forms within a form

Tags: html

I have three separate forms, which need to be part of a single 'larger' form. **I can merge them to form a single form, but that is not my intention.** I need to do something like this:

```
<form method="" action="">

    <form1 without method and action>

    </form>

    <form2 without method and action>

    </form>

    <form3 without method and action>

    </form>

</form>
```

such that the data from the three forms can be collectively sent to the 'outer' form. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why you don't want to have just one form?  A form without method or action is pointless in itself and definitely will not validate.

Comment: why not have different divs? i.e. <div id=Parent-Div> Add Form > Insert another DIV > Add another Form /<div> etc...

Comment: I need three similar forms side by side. The front end have designed using CSS to position them, and if I alter that portion, it messes up the whole thing, which I want to avoid. i.e. removing the <div> or <form> tags to merge them places the contents in an abrupt way.

Comment: What you want is not valid, but if you explain **why** you want it, or show us a site that does what you want, we can tell you how to do it.

Comment: Either make one big form, and do the formatting in CSS using the div's only. One form can have multiple submit buttons, so you can add three different submit buttons, and have the serverside check which button was pushed; or make three small forms.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve with this - what are the exact requirement that lead you to this idea?

Comment: @Konerak: Sorry. I am not aware of any such site. I need to escape working on the CSS to position the form elements, as replacing the <form> with the <div> does not yield results.

Comment: @Oded: No idea as such. Looking for an alternative to working on CSS.

Comment: You are basically saying you don't know what you are trying to do. How are we supposed to help then?

Comment: @Oded: Let me put it clear. As of now there are three separate forms with three submit buttons, vertically aligned to each other. - *That is due to the tag <form class = ""> in each of the three forms.* Now I need to use a single submit button. But replacing the <form> tags with <div> does not do good to the CSS.

Comment: That's a _very_ different question from what you asked. You should have asked - "how can I have a single submit button for 3 different forms?". You have asked about what you think is a solution instead of asking about the actual issue you have.

Comment: @Oded: Thanks. That made me arrive at the solution myself. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not valid HTML.

A `FORM` is not allowed to have nested forms.

From the [DTD for HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html):

```
<!ELEMENT FORM - - (%block;|SCRIPT)+ -(FORM) -- interactive form -->
```

The `-(FORM)` explicitly excludes this.

You can have a single form and simply hide the unneeded elements using javascript.

Answer (score 6):

It is invalid to put a form element inside a form element, and it is invalid to have a form with no defined method or action. Resulting behaviour is therefore undefined and, on the off-chance that it happens to work, it can't be relied on.

I can't see any reason for wanting/needing this kind of layout, when a single form should be fine.

Are you maybe looking for something like the `<fieldset>` element?

Comment: Not necessarily that. Instead of altering the CSS, I am trying for an alternative way.

Comment: `method` has a default value of `GET` and is thus not required to be explicitly stated.

Comment: @user980411: An alternative way to do _what_?

Answer (score 3):

No, nested forms are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all nested forms are not allowed, instead what you can do is

```
<form>
<div class="step1">
feilds
</div>
<div class="step2">
feilds
</div>
<div class="step3">
feilds
</div>
</form>
```

wont this work for you?

Comment: Tried that. But the front end team has designed the page in such a way that using <div> the contents don't appear, while using <form> instead of <div> in your example, arranges the contents in the desired way.

Comment: @user980411, then the page design needs a major fix, or possibly redesign.

Comment: its probably the css styling they have added to the form tags...if that's the case then the page definitely needs to be update with a proper markup first i.e it should be as easy as replacing your nested form structure with divs keeping the css unchanged.